# is it possible to have twitter log out in ios app?

Tags: ios, twitter

i have used tweet sheet to tweet in my app,which works fine but can’t log out after setting ..i have to re launch the app to tweet
but what i want is to make a separate login button but in twitter is it possible to login and log out from twitter inside app? 
Thanks loads in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. You have to logout in your phones Settings.

Comment: i am afraid you are right , anyway thanks for your response btype

Comment: it isn't possible because that would counter the single sign on design in Twitter Integration.

Comment: yeah i have btype :) i was just waiting for a answer were i can return to app after twitter settings

Comment: If I invalidate the token ? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/invalidate_token

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your own UI for Twitter login. E.g. once user entered twitter credentials you can first add Twitter account and then call Tweet sheet.

I doubt if log out or delete account is possible using SDK.

Sample code to add twitter account:

```
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init] ;

        ACAccountType *twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if(granted) {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:[store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter]];

                ACAccountCredential *outhCredential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token.key tokenSecret:token.secret];
                twitterAccount.credential = outhCredential;

                [store saveAccount:twitterAccount withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    if(success)
                    {
                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showTweetSheet) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                    }
                }];

                [outhCredential release];
                [twitterAccount release];
                [store release];
            }
            // Handle any error state here as you wish
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks MSK for your response:) i have code too sign in to twitter but pls can u give some sample code to sign out from settings of the twitter..

Comment: @iShuru I quickly searched the documentation and now I think there is no way to delete account (or sign out) from within an app. So in a way login is possible but not log off.

Comment: MSK yeah :( hopefully twitter update there framework soon .. but can we do dismissviewcontroller or something like that to some how come back to app from twitter settings?

Comment: If you mean returning to your app from settings app, the ans is NO